# What is the purpose of {{render}} and {{control}} in ember pre4

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

There seems to be zero documentation for these handlebars helpers. Can someone explain what they do and how best to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{render}} uses the same named controller and template in the current context. If a view class with the same name exists, it uses that view class. If a model is specified, it becomes the model for that controller. Default target will be that same controller.

{{control}} uses a new instance of the named controller, instead of a singleton of the named controller.

{{partial}} dumps the same template into place, with the same container, and the current controller. The template name must start with an underscore.

Comment: Thank you. Examples of syntax would be nice as well.

Comment: {{partial "navigation}} would find a template named "navigation", you can also do {{partial "navigation/sidebar"}} if you want to look inside directories. This is the simplest way to just get something on the page. {{render "person" person}} would use App.PersonController, App.PersonView, App.PersonRoute, and in this case, we specified the model, so the content of App.PersonController will be that particular person. Any actions you use will first be looked for in the PersonController, but if not, it will try to look in PersonRoute.

Comment: {{control}} has the same syntax as render, except that it uses a new instance of the named controller, App.PersonController, except it's a new instance. I don't really know when to use control rather than render though.